# How to add a pattern from a 2D image on a 3D object?

Tags: objects, text-object

I am new to blender.

I have a 3D object that are made from an SVG file.

I want to know how to apply an image to said object. To act like a skin for said 3D object. This is the same as creating a clipping mask in Adobe Photoshop.

How do I apply said image to an object to make it act as a skin for the 3D object?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate, but I can't find the other question atm. My suggestion would be to import a vector and extrude that.

Comment: Thanks @veryRandomMe . It is not the duplicate of that question. I have an object formed the same as the question you mentioned. But, I want to apply an image to act like a skin to said object.

Comment: Sounds to me liek you are wanting to have the image applied as a texture to your svg curve object - in this case, the best I can suggest is to convert with alt-c to mesh and then add an image texture mapped to UVs, projected from top view if the svg object is still on the x and y plane.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "To act like a skin" and the reference to PS's clipping mask is not making anything clearer.  Do you mean that you just want to texture the object, or put on image on the surface of it?

Comment: Thanks @CraigDJones . I'll try that. Apparently I have to learn what is texture in blender. Sorry for that. Hahaha.

Comment: Thanks @David ,  If I want to put an image on the surface, how do I do it?

Comment: I reckon the word you are looking for is the "(image) texture" as mentioned above. Texture is something that is applied to a surface of a 3d object to give it details. I believe this was asked before but cannot find it. In the meantime, you can google "Blender texture tutorial" to find wonderful tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Put a Black and White image into an image texture and use it in a displacement modifier applied to a highly subdivided plane.